# Laravel 5 обработка запроса

Tags: php, laravel

Приходят данный kitchen, average_bills, district
нужно обработать варианты, в запросе могут быть как по отдельности так и например kitchen, average_bills, или на оборот
пробывал так

```
if(Request::only('kitchen')){
        $restos = Resto::whereHas('kitchens', function ($query)use ($kitchen) {
                $query->where('id', $kitchen);
            })
            ->get();
    }elseif(Request::only('district')){
        $restos = Resto::where(function($q )use ($district)
        {

            $q->where('district', '=', $district);

        })
            ->get();
    }elseif(Request::only('average_bills')){
        $restos = Resto::where(function($q )use ($average_bills)
        {
            $q->where('average_bills', '=', $average_bills);


        })
            ->get();
    }else{
        $restos = Resto::where(function($q )use ($average_bills,$district)
        {
            $q->where('average_bills', '=', $average_bills);
            $q->where('district', '=', $district);

        })
            ->whereHas('kitchens', function ($query)use ($kitchen) {
                $query->where('id', $kitchen);
            })
            ->get();
    }


    return $restos;
```

но не работает? что можно исправить или сделать по другому ? помогите кто сталкивался?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если обратиться к справочной информации Laravel, то можно увидеть, что

```
Reques::only()
```

возвращает массив и поэтому ваши условия вида

```
if(Request::only('kitchen'))
```

будут работать не корректно, для проверки на наличие в реквести определенного параметра лучше использовать

```
if (Request::has('name'))
{
    //code
}
```

так же можно сразу получить значение параметра, в случае отсутсвия будет NULL

```
Request::input('name');
```

или со значением по умолчанию

```
Request::input('name', 'Vasia');
```

больше по ссылке :)

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests

## UPDATE

сделайте тогда, что-то вроде

```
if(Request::has('kitchen')){
 //code
}

if(Request::has('distinct')){
//code
}
```

и тд

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но даже has срабатывает не правильно

Comment: посмотрел код, у вас условие не правильно, в вашем случае сейчас так, если у вас в параметра будет и district и kitchen тогда обработается только kitchen, я поправил ответ, смотрите его

Comment: я же говорю has работает не правильно :) у меня идет выборка из модели например если пришло kitchen и district то вывести те объекты у которых совпадают эти поля в таблице, а тут он выдает все что есть в бд у которых есть такие значения по отдельности

Comment: можете еще чем то помочь ?

Comment: @Rai покажите ваш код через has

Comment: http://laravel.io/bin/Yy406

Comment: ну тут с ifами вы напутали чего-то) Я бы написал в итоге вот так http://pastebin.com/EgS9Ww0F

Comment: Спасибо за решение этой задачи! самое то!! :)